# In Xamarin, is there a limit to how much can be stored in Application.Current.Properties?

Tags: mobile, xamarin

We have started to use the Application.Current.Properties more and more and we want to make sure we won't run into any issues. Does it have a limit of any sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Xamarin Forms just serializes that data to json/xml and saves it to the file system.  So there is a danger of filling up the filesystem if you really overuse it (you would probably have memory issues before that happened) - but other than that I don't think I would be too concerned.